# is it possible to talk to a javascript chat bot via commandline

Tags: azure, chatbot

I have a list of questions im trying to use to train an azure chatbot. But I don't want to copy and paste them from my list to the bot in the browser, it will take forever. Is there a curl/post/etc command I can use to target the chat window?  I was thinking of a way of sniffing my current request when i type a question and just changing the field but wasn't sure if something like that is possible

Comment: Did you analyze the request with the F12 tools?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, analyze the request in your console log (F12), it's guaranteed to be a REST interface unless it was written 15 years ago.  The only thing that could throw a wrench in your gears is if they are keeping state in the browser and communicating that state to the server somehow.  That would be impossible to replicate.  But you should be able to see that in the body of the request if it's not completely obfuscated.

Once you have the request figured out, curl should work fine if you understand their REST interface.